# APS - export PDF with color overrides by setThemingColor

Tags: autodesk-forge

Found this blog article about merging PDF with markups in Autodesk Platforms Service Viewer.
[blog link](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/merge-pdfs-svg-texts)

Is it possible to adapt in order to include color overrides made with viewer.setThemingColor?

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be challenging since the approach used in the blog shared relies on [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org) to add SVGs on top of the PDF.

The only way I see to achieve this is by retrieving the boundary of the geometry with color being overridden and then placing an SVG shape on top of that. The issue with this approach is that when you use setThemingColor, it considers the "layer" of the elements.

For example, let's consider the situation below:

[image: initial image]

If you use setThemingColor, you'll still be able to see the labels for the Deck:

[image: setthemingcolor]

While if you add SVG through PDF-LIB, it will be placed on top of the labels:

[image: SVG override color]

If this behavior isn't a problem, you can use PDF-LIB methods to add texts, paths, or anything supported on top of your PDFs.

If this is an issue, then you'll need to change the input file and then translate it once more. Depending on your workflow, that can be achieved with [Design Automation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/overview/)